# Terminal output corrupted [npm - eth-gas-reporter]

Tags: npm, terminal, blockchain, ethereum, hardhat

[Terminal output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OutQa.png) - some random characters instead of:
[eth gas reporter output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDxTb.png)
[image]

That's the output when running `npx hardhat test` with the gas-reporter module

os: **Mac osx 12.0.1**
terminal emulator: **Iterm2**
font: **Hack Nerd Font**
shell: **zsh**

also tested with other fonts, other terminal emulators, and shells.
Running `npx hardhat test > out.txt` - redirecting output to file also does contain corrupted data

I'm pretty sure that this shows correctly on Linux
I used same terminal app (Iterm2) to connect to linux server and ran same command and it shows up correctly: [image: Correct output]

Comment: Looks like you're outputting binary data to the terminal. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119480/why-and-how-did-using-cat-on-binary-files-mess-up-the-terminal)

Comment: Nope it isn't binary, I used ssh (same terminal) to connect to linux server and run that command and everything looks good
@JordanBonecutter

Answer (score 0):

FIXED by updating hardhat-eth-gas-reporter npm module to 1.0.7